# Why difference in publish output between visual studio 2017 and azure devops in .net core 2.1?

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

When trying to publish my .net core mvc application to a folder, it is IIS friendly whereas when i tried to publish the same source in azure devops pipelines, it creates almost hundreds of files which is not IIS friendly. Why both differs or what i need to do to have azure publish works the same way as visual studios.

Have gone through troubleshooting azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#package-and-deliver-your-code) and couldnt find it useful to this problem.

Adding azure-pipeline.yml content below

```
    trigger:
    - dev

    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

    variables:
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
      a: dotnet --version

    steps:
    - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
    - bash: echo $(a)

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: True
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: True

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
        artifactName: 'Vinocopia_Redesign'

    - task: FtpUpload@1
      inputs:
        credentialsOption: 'inputs'
        serverUrl: 'ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx'# Required when credentialsOption == Inputs
        username: 'username'# Required when credentialsOption == Inputs
        password: 'pwd'# Required when credentialsOption == Inputs
        rootDirectory: 
        filePatterns: '**' 
        remoteDirectory: '/upload/$(Build.BuildId)/' 
        #clean: false 
        #cleanContents: false # Required when clean == False
        overwrite: false 
        #preservePaths: false 
        #trustSSL: false
```

Comment: You just said the different, but you did not provide any indication that they are different and how did you publish it in the Azure devops? Your question is too broad to give a answer. So, please provide the different output and the build definition about build/publish task. It will help us to find the reason for this different.

Comment: /but you did not provide any indication that they are different/... File count and IIS friendly(when we point IIS application to the published folder it works for vs publish whereas azure devops publish didnt). Will add azure-pipeline.yml code here

Comment: @ArulManivannan there is no "azure devops publish" but "dotnet publish" ;) and yes  "dotnet publish" and "vs publish" are differenz methods of publishing so please do not try to compare them... either use "vs publish"-method in devops or try to get the "dotnet publish"-method to run locally as intended so you can updated your "dotnet publish"-step in the yaml

Comment: "vs publish" would be "msbuild xxx.sln /p:deployonbuild=true" in a commandline task with additional properties but that is for you to figure out

Answer (score 1):

> Why difference in publish output between visual studio 2017 and azure devops in .net core 2.1?

Just like D.J pointed:

> **"dotnet publish" and "vs publish" are differenz methods of publishing**

If you want get the same result with you get from Visual Studio publish, you should use Visual Studio/MSBuild publish instead of dotnet publish, so we need use Visual Studio build
 with MSBuild arguments like following:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: NetCoreMVC/NetCoreMVC.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:publishUrl="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for specifying. Do i need to replace dotnet publish with vs publish? if i do so, i receive an error invalid command.

Comment: @ArulManivannan, Yes, you need replace it.